# Open Balls Needed!

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can anyone think of a two open balls $S(x,r_1)$ and $S(y,r_2)$ in metric space $R$ such that $S(x,r_1)$ contains $S(y,r_2)$ even though $r_2 > r_1$?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Depends on what your definition of "contains" is.

Comment: Define contains

Comment: Oh, and while you're at it, what is an "open sphere"? You mean "open ball" as opposed to sphere?

Comment: Best classified ad I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Contain as in every point in one ball is in the other

Comment: Classified ad? What do you mean?

Comment: I think open ball and open sphere are synonyms

Comment: Not in mathematical English. A sphere is a set of points at *fixed* radius, and a ball is what is inside. I would highly encourage you to rewrite, using the word ball. ("Weird balls needed" might sound a bit more lurid, but what the ...)

Comment: Ahh, understood then. I refer to a open ball then

Comment: At any rate, much easier to solve with open balls. I think one cannot solve it for spheres.

Comment: I finally got zhw's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define distance $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$ and $d(x,y ) = 1$ otherwise.

Choose $S(x, 21)$ and $S(y, 4)$.

(If $r>1$, then the open ball $S(z, r)$ equals the entire space, for all $z$.)